# Get values from string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

How to get the error number and error description from this string

s = "ERR: 100, out of credit";

error should equal "100"
error description should equal "out of credit"

Comment: surely you could figure this out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string message = "ERR: 100, out of credit";
string[] parts = message.Split(new char[] { ',' });
string[] error = parts[0].Split(new char[] { ':' });

string errorNumber = error[1].Trim();
string errorDescription = parts[1].Trim();
```

Answer (score 3):

If the format is always ERR: "code", "desc" you could do some regex on it pretty easily.  In C#:

string s = "ERR: 100, out of credit";

Match m = Regex.Match(s, "ERR: ([^,]*), (.*)");

string error = m.Groups[1].Value;
string description = m.Groups[2].Value;

Comment: Have to go with BrokenGlass on this one. Regexes are inefficient compared to splits.

Answer (score 0):

string s = "ERR: 100, out of credit";

Match m = Regex.Match(s, "[ERR:\s*]\d+");
Match n = Regex.Match(s, "(?<=ERR: \d+, ).+");
string errorno = m.value
string errordesc = n.value

hope this will useful